# Drush (or equivalent) on windows azure for drupal automation?

Tags: windows, azure, drupal-7, drush

I am setting up a drupal multi-site environment on windows-azure (*webrole/cloud service*). [**Drush**](http://www.drush.org/) is a great command-line tool and necessary for maintaining several multi-sites at once.

Windows Azure integration for Drupal is quite good, but I haven't found anything about automation over command-line-interface on windows azure.

Has anyone ever made experience with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is quite easy set up Drush on Azure. You just need to put the Drush files and folders in the web role's resource folder and run a Startup Task to register "drush" to the PATH variable.